# MDB tag eradicated

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

See here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105117/168681 for problem description.

Having done dung-beetle work of manual retagging about 150 "mdb" questions (took me about 5 months), I hereby announce the "mdb" tag as extinct and I'm asking to lock it permanently, due to ambiguity of the acronym.

The tag was used in the meaning of:

- message driven bean (about 70%),
- MS Access database (about 30%),
- a Unix debugger (twice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I synonymized  [mdb](/questions/tagged/mdb) --> [msaccess](/questions/tagged/msaccess), since it's a file extension.

Banning is usually reserved for meta-tags, off-topic tags and other similar nonsense.

Comment: Have the [`headache` and `frustration`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116328/169101?headache-and-frustration-tag-blocking-request) tags already been blacklisted?

Comment: That's the problem - it cannot, as you'd have to synonymize it to multiple tags.

Comment: Not really... We pick one tag, and go with it.

Comment: So, who's going to go through and fix all those message-driven bean questions that now claim to be about access databases?

Comment: @DonalFellows: Link, or it didn't happen.

Comment: Thanks. I'd synonymize it to "message-driven-bean", but the most important thing is that it's clear now.